# How to change row values with calculation in R

Tags: r, transform, calculation

I need some help with my data frame (df) in R. I need to transform existing row values with some calculation and I don't know how to apply it to every row I need. I have gross domestic product and I need to change it obsValues with calculation that includes CPI row values : (GDP/CPI)*100. The most difficult thing here is that GDP and CPI are in rows not in columns...

My dataframe looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpXxZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73eyr.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the `dput` of a small data so that it can be tested

Comment: Maybe not tested (`library(dplyr);library(stringr);df1 <- df1 %>% group_by(obsTime) %>% mutate(obsValue2 = obsValue[SUBJECT_DEF == "Gross domestic product"]/obsValue[str_detect(SUBJECT_DEF, "CPI:")] * 100)`

Comment: Try the code above.  It works if all the obsTime have only a single Gross domestic product and 'CPI:' row

Comment: Data is shown quarterly, so GDP and CPI will have different obsvalues every quarter

Comment: Basedon the image you showed, `obsTime` seems to be unique grouping as it has both year and quarter information

Comment: Try the code and see if there are any errors

Comment: this code you wrote gives me additional column, but the problem is that I need to change existing obsvalues to that calculation. Also when I run this code I get new obsvalues2 in  every SUBJECT_DEF, but I need them only near SUBJECT_DEF == "Gross domestic product"

Comment: I was just testing it so that your original column doesn't change even if there is any mistake (otherwise you have to redo the whole sourcing again).  You just need `mutate(obsValue = obsValue, ..` instead of `obsValue2`

Comment: okay, but then as I mentioned all rows changes by this calculation and I need to change only those, which have SUBJECT_DEF == "Gross domestic product"

Comment: Try the code in the solution I posted below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may do

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 <- df1 %>% 
       group_by(obsTime) %>% 
       mutate(obsValue = replace(obsValue, 
        SUBJECT_DEF == "Gross domestic product", 
        obsValue[SUBJECT_DEF == "Gross domestic product"]/
         obsValue[str_detect(SUBJECT_DEF, "CPI:")] * 100)) %>%
      ungroup
```